# Interference between expandableListView children

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I'm having some issues implementing an expandableListView. I had implemented my ExpandableListAdapter

public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

```
private static final int SUM = 1;
private static final int SUB = 2;

private Context context;
private List<String> listDataHeader;    //Header titles
private HashMap<String, List<Article>> listDataChild;
private HashMap<Integer, Bitmap> productImagesHashMap;

public ExpandableListAdapter (Context context, List<String> listDataHeader, HashMap<String, List<Article>> listDataChild, HashMap<Integer, Bitmap> productImagesHashMap) {
    this.context = context;
    this.listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
    this.listDataChild = listDataChild;
    this.productImagesHashMap = productImagesHashMap;
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return this.listDataHeader.size();
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return this.listDataChild.get(this.listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return this.listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return this.listDataChild.get(this.listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.user_expand_listview_header, null);
    }

    TextView listHeaderTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_header);
    listHeaderTextView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    listHeaderTextView.setText(headerTitle);

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                         boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final Article childValues = (Article) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.product_row, null);
    }

    Integer articleId = childValues.getId();

    final TextView articleIdTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.product_id);
    ImageView productImageTextView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.product_image);
    TextView productNameTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.product_name);
    TextView productDescriptionTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.product_description);
    final TextView productPriceTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.product_price);

    articleIdTextView.setText(articleId.toString());
    productImageTextView.setImageBitmap(productImagesHashMap.get(articleId));
    productNameTextView.setText(childValues.getNome());
    productDescriptionTextView.setText(childValues.getDescrizione());
    productPriceTextView.setText(childValues.getPrezzo());

    ImageButton addButton = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.add_btn);
    final TextView articleQty =(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.product_qnty);
    ImageButton removeButton = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.remove_btn);

    addButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (context instanceof UserActivity) {
                ((UserActivity) context).updateTotal(
                        Integer.parseInt(articleIdTextView.getText().toString()),
                        productPriceTextView.getText().toString(),
                        SUM);
                articleQty.setText(updateProductQty(articleQty, SUM));
            }
        }
    });

    removeButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (context instanceof UserActivity) {
                ((UserActivity) context).updateTotal(
                        Integer.parseInt(articleIdTextView.getText().toString()),
                        productPriceTextView.getText().toString(),
                        SUB);
                articleQty.setText(updateProductQty(articleQty, SUB));
            }
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int i, int i1) {
    return true;
}

private String updateProductQty(TextView productQty, int operation) {
    Integer qty = Integer.parseInt(productQty.getText().toString());
    switch (operation) {
        case 1: //SUM
            qty += 1;
            break;
        case 2: //SUB
            if (qty > 0)
                qty -= 1;
            break;
    }
    return qty.toString();
}
```

}

There are some products that are read from a database and inserted in the ExpandableListView by type (Actually Pens, Notebooks and Paper). Then there are two button that allow to select how many of them the user want to buy, the quantity is tracked by a TextView. Now, when I implemented this with a normal ListView all worked, but with ExpandableListView there are interference between quantity TextView of children.

For example, the actual composition of the ExpandableListView is that:

Pens

-- Black Pen

-- Blue Pen

-- Red Pen

Notebooks

-- Black Notebook

-- Blue Notebook

-- Red Notebook

Paper

-- A4 Paper

If the user add a black notebook, a blue pen is also added

If the user add a blue notebook, a black pen is also added

If the user add a red notebook, a blue pen is also added

Why there are these interference?

Comment: Did u try to debug ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not tracking your quantity updates properly.

Since `ExpandableListView` -- like `ListView` -- recycles its views, you get this behavior:

- User presses Add button for black notebook.
- User scrolls/expands/collapses list.
- View for blue pen is created by recycling view from black notebook.
- View for blue pen is displayed with quantity from black notebook.

This is what you need to do:

- Add a quantity property to `Article` class
- When creating child view, populate `articleQty` `TextView` with the quantity contained in that `Article` object.
- When user presses Add/Remove buttons, update quantity in the `Article` object and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

The rule is: View is populated from model, model is updated from listener. Don't use the listener to update the view, calling `notifyDataSetcChanged()` will take care of that.

Comment: Thaks, it works! That exactly what I neet to know :D